# convert mayavi scene into e.g. PIL image without rendering it first

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mayavi

I am looking for a way to convert a 3D scene from mayavi into a python image format like PIL. I read the documentation but nothing really fits my need. Is it possible to do that in an efficient manner, e.g. a loop over scenes without rendering every one of it first?

Comment: doesn't [`savefig()`](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_figure.html#savefig) work for you?

Comment: it does, I even figured out, how to save it, without rendering it to the screen first. Thank you!